# Should I use Ngrx in Ionic 5?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngrx

I have few concerns when using ngrx in mobile app with Ionic 5:

1. Performance issues on mobile devices. = ngrx is state management so all data from API will be stored in memory and accessible all the time. Could this effect some older devices(e.g. android 4.4)?
2. Too much ngrx boilerplate can increase app bundle size.
3. Can't use ngrx/data due to a lot of [limitations](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-ngrx-data/blob/master/docs/limitations.md)..
4. ngrx is 3rd party library. Is it 100% compatible with Ionic Angular?

Is there anyone out there who has faced the similar issues?

Comment: I've released an ionic/angular app using ngrx. It's working fine. NGRX is not responsible for that huge amount of increase in the bundle size as you think. Also, the unavoidable amount of code you have to use for redux work (that's not a privilege of NGRX alone - the pattern demands it) is the price for having it controlling your app data. For simple data, you can rely on ngrx/data, but it hardly fits more complex scenarios. In summary, just go for it. I've never regret using redux in an app.

Comment: Additionally to NGRX I have firebase and its reactive database approach. Fantastic combination!

Comment: It's good to hear this. ngrx/data is off, because app is too complex, it has a lot of API calls with different queries. Does your app work fine with older devices?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found an old-enough device to test it. All my tests were made in, at most, 2-years old devices (Motorola G6 and Zen phone 2. To use an IOS device you must have an apple store paid account, which I don't). BTW I'm using capacitor. I have submitted my app to some skeptic developers, who loved to criticize ionic in favor of other technologies. After using the app for a little bit, 100% of them asked me if I had used flutter (which I love). Nobody, by just using an app, can tell the difference after the app is ready.  And the native look and feel of ionic is incredible.

Comment: About my comment above: that limitation concerning the paid account imposed by IOS is not intentional. Apparently it's a bug in IOS and the rest of Apple ecosystem that is preventing capacitor-based apps to be uploaded to apple store using a free developer account or installing it directly in the device. It's related to security measures taken by Apple latest OS versions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, I didn't know about capacitor and free account... I love working in ionic, it;s very easy to use. I think that hybrid frameworks like Ionic are future (present) of mobile development. Just like you said nobody, by using an app, can tell difference about technologies used.

Comment: But, unfortunately, there's a lot of prejudgement in the market. Ionic is not a loved technology as, for example, flutter. A huge online bank (NuBank) has decided to migrate all of it app to flutter after considering a few technologies. Someone of their dev team even wrote about it. Among all the techs they've considered and tested, ionic wasn't there. I've asked them why and the answer was too vague, but it seems they were trying to avoid greater discussions/divisions inside the company (they've chosen flutter).

Comment: I've seen an article (I don't remember where) comparing technologies (not just mobile frameworks - it was more like "which are the techs you should invest in for the future"). In that blog article, Ionic was considered the worst technology to learn in 2020, because, based on the numbers shown in downloads, forums, and version-control services, it appears to be dying in the long term in favor of other new techs. In the mobile world, the current bet is Google's Flutter.

Comment: Usually banks are using very old tech(I know some banks are still using Angular 1.x).  I never used flutter in project buy I think it doesn't have a high level of customization and plugins like Ionic. We had a luck to convince few customers(insurance-tech) to go with Ionic and the main reason was because they already had few web apps with angular.

Comment: For an angular developer, learn the basics of ionic is almost a matter of learning a new design system. It takes a week, at most.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used Ionic, I'm using NgRx in Angular projects but never needed to use them together.

Yet, I believe it is a good choice (quite recommended) to use NgRx for state management in an Ionic-Angular project.

1. Nowadays, devices have enough resources to handle an NgRx store state management just as React Native apps use Redux, so I wouldn't worry about that.
2. Depending on the complexity of your app it can increase the bundle size, but not in a critical manner, especially if the build is treeshakeable
3. can't share an opinion over this
4. yes it is. You can check this [article](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-ngrx-for-state-management-in-an-ionic-angular-application/) to get an insight

Comment: I've used Ionic and ngrx too but never together. My main concern would be what if I store a large response (few MB) by accident. As I said I am concerned about older devices. Maybe I am too careful :)

Comment: I don't know what kind of data will you be processing but generally, only media data (images, videos, etc) sky rock the file size. 
Hence, if you store ordinary objects (simple properties like id, name, quantity, etc) or list of objects, even for let's say 1000 stored objects I don't think the json size will be big enough to make a difference.
Don't take my word for granted since it's just an assumption but you might be indeed overly cautious. 
Anyways, best of luck

Comment: Thanks! I will not store media files that's for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

Do you actually need it?
According to [NgRx documentation](https://ngrx.io/docs) the base requirements should meet the SHARI principle. I would ignore the performance issues that seems to be null couse obviously an Ionic App runs in what is barely a normal browser (you can check it [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/preface.html)).

If your app requirements share the SHARI principle why not to use NgRx